# asmack - receiving custom XML messages

Tags: java, android, xmpp

I'm sending custom XML messages from server to clients. An Android is a client which should know how to handle custom XML messages. The problem with asmack (which I'm using for receiving/sending messages) is that it tries to parse the message itself. An example message of the playerlist is the following:

```
<html xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im">
<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <players xmlns="boxer:players" command="playerlist">
    <player>test1</player>
    <player>test2</player>
  </players>
</body>
</html>
```

In Android, I'm adding a custom Extenstion Provider with:

```
ProviderManager.getInstance().addExtensionProvider("html","http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im", new XMLPlayerListProvider());
```

And the XMLPlayerListProvider

```
class XMLPlayerListProvider implements PacketExtensionProvider {
  public XMLPlayerListProvider() {}

  public PacketExtension parseExtension(XmlPullParser parser) {
    Log.w("**********HHHHHHHHHHHHH***********", "0");
    boolean stop = false;
    int evtType;
    String n;
    String id = null;
    Log.w("START: "+XmlPullParser.START_TAG, "0");
    while (!stop) {
      try {
       evtType = parser.next();
       n = parser.getName();
       switch (evtType) {
          case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
             if ("body".equals(n))
                Log.w("BODY"+n.toString(), "0"); 
             else if ("players".equals(n))
                Log.w("PLAYERS", "0");
             else if ("player".equals(n))
                Log.w("PLAYER", "0");
             break;
          case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
             //Stop parsing when we hit </item>
             stop = "body".equals(n);
             break;
       }
      } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    return new XMLPlayerList();
  } 
}



class XMLPlayerList implements PacketExtension {

  public String getElementName() {
    return "aaaaa";
  }

  public String getNamespace() {
    return "aaaaa";
  }

  public String toXML() {
    return "aaaaa";
  }

}
```

When debugging I'm getting the following output:

```
W/**********HHHHHHHHHHHHH***********(  654): 0
W/START: 2(  654): 0
W/BODYbody(  654): 0
D/SMACK   (  654): 11:11:58 PM RCV  (1156379984): mand="playerlist">
D/SMACK   (  654): <player>test1</player>
D/SMACK   (  654): <player>test2</player>
D/SMACK   (  654): </players>
D/SMACK   (  654): </body></html><thread>8rOVz0</thread></message><iq
W/PLAYERS (  654): 0
W/PLAYER  (  654): 0
W/PLAYER  (  654): 0
W/RESPONSE: <message id="15" to="eee@localhost" from="admin@localhost" type="chat"><body>
test1
test2

</body><thread>
```

Here we can see that something strange is going on, but the PacketExtension is indeed getting called. My question now is: how can I change the XMLPlayerListProvider to receive the basic XML message without it being parsed by the default Android packet extension, which I guess is what's outputed as:

```
test1
test2
```

That should be:

```
  <players xmlns="boxer:players" command="playerlist">
    <player>test1</player>
    <player>test2</player>
  </players>
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you're wrapping the message in HTML tags and using an existing XMPP namespace? Possibly the XHTML-IM parser is picking up your messages and parsing them?

Comment: It was only for testing, I've changed it now to <message>. And I can't define my own class for that, because there's a listener "public void processMessage(Chat c, Message m) { }", which accepts Message as input parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you not override existing providers by trying to parse existing namespaces, since that will only cause confusion and possible errors (as mentioned by @Christopher)

Try using the [EmbeddedExtensionProvider](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/provider/EmbeddedExtensionProvider.html) to do your parsing as it takes care of most of the tag handling for you, and simplify your custom xml to what you need only.  Which appears to be the **players** element.