# How to get custom attribute value from an XMPP XML message?

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

Ok guys, simple question but pretty important to me.

so, other android client are sending this xml msg:

```
<message
  id='6ymdM-19'
  to='xox@xox.xox/smack'
  type='chat'>
  <subject>normal</subject>
  <received xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts' id='HVgQw-5'/>
</message>
```

and my listener is roughly like this:

```
private class MsgListener implements ChatStateListener {
/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public MsgListener() {
}

@Override
public void processMessage(Chat chat, org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message message) {
    String xmlMessage = message.toXML();
    Log.v(TAG, "XML Chat: "+xmlMessage);
    // getExtension namespace try urn:xmpp:receipts
    if(xmlMessage.contains("<request xmlns=")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "new chat message arrive! reply with RECEIVED!");
        replyReceived(message);
    } else if(xmlMessage.contains("<received xmlns=")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "RECEIVED notification arrived!");
        PacketExtension statusExtension = 
                message.getExtension("urn:xmpp:receipts");
        Log.d(TAG, "Extension name: "+statusExtension.getElementName());
        Log.d(TAG, "Extension XML: "+statusExtension.toXML());
        Log.d(TAG, "Extension string: "+statusExtension.toString());
    }

     ....
     ....
     ....
}
```

in this case I want to get the value of attribute "id", inside the "received" element tag.
but what I got on my Log is like this:

```
RECEIVED notification arrived!
D/ChatAdapter(320): Extension name: received
D/ChatAdapter(320): Extension XML: <received xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></received>
D/ChatAdapter(320): Extension string:              
org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.DefaultPacketExtension@44f10430
```

So how I can get the 'HVgQw-5' ??

**UPDATE**

Actually there's something weird...
I have receive the xml accordinh from my SMACK debug like this:

```
 <
 D/SMACK(320): 05:40:28 PM RCV  (1156991856): message id="6ymdM-19"  
 to="syeikh@emass.sangkuriang.co.id/Smack" from="emu22@emass.sangkuriang.co.id/Smack"  
 type="chat"><subject>
 D/SMACK(320): 05:40:28 PM RCV  (1156991856): normal</subject><thread>cr0900</thread>
 **<received xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts" id="HVgQw-5"/>**<active      
 xmlns="http://jabber.org/protoc
 D/SMACK(320): 05:40:28 PM RCV  (1156991856): ol/chatstates"/></message>
```

But when I execute message.toXML it's just print out like this:

```
XML Chat: <message id="6ymdM-19" to="syeikh@emass.sangkuriang.co.id/Smack" from="emu22@emass.sangkuriang.co.id/Smack" type="chat"><subject>normal</subject><thread>cr0900</thread>**<received xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts">**</received><active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates" /></message>
```

Why this is happening? why do I miss the "id" ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

About the ID, first get a handle on extension then look for ID, so

```
DeliveryReceipt deliveryReceiptObj =(DeliveryReceipt) message.getExtension(DeliveryReceipt.NAMESPACE);
// ID below is what you want
deliveryReceiptObj.getId();
```

Related discussion: 
[asmack - receiving custom XML messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887073/asmack-receiving-custom-xml-messages)

1. define your `EmbeddedPacketExtension` ( so you get a handle on this instead of  `DefaultPacketExtension` provided by SMACK )
2. A provider that extends `EmbeddedExtensionProvider`
3. `registerProvider` you just created with Namespace

code follows:

```
/**
* User: suvrat 
* Represents a <b>message delivery receipt</b> entry as specified by
* <a href="http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html">Message Delivery Receipts</a>.
*
*/

import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.PacketExtension;

public class DeliveryReceipt implements PacketExtension
{

    public static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:xmpp:receipts";

    private String id; /// original ID of the delivered message

    public DeliveryReceipt(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getElementName()
    {
        return "received";
    }

    public String getNamespace()
    {
        return NAMESPACE;
    }

    public String toXML()
    {
        return "<received xmlns='" + NAMESPACE + "' id='" + id + "'/>";
    }
}

 /**
 * User: suvrat
 * The DeliveryReceiptProvider parses DeliveryReceipt packets.
 */

 */
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.PacketExtension;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.EmbeddedExtensionProvider;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class DeliveryReceiptProvider extends EmbeddedExtensionProvider
{

    @Override
    protected PacketExtension createReturnExtension(String currentElement, String currentNamespace,
    Map<String, String> attributeMap, List<? extends PacketExtension> content)
    {
        return new DeliveryReceipt(attributeMap.get("id"));
    }

}

   //3.) finally where ever you would like to parse packet
 ProviderManager.getInstance().addExtensionProvider("received", DeliveryReceipt.NAMESPACE, new DeliveryReceiptProvider());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve it without modifying the source code. And the proper approach in XMPP is to create extensions to the standard packets, not modify them.
You can refer to [Cannot Read Custom Attributes From Message TAG when using asmack XMPP library for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454025/cannot-read-custom-attributes-from-message-tag-when-using-asmack-xmpp-library-fo)， which provides the details.

Answer (score 0):

There exists another way to get attribute value, which defines the method UserInfo4XMPP by implementing ExtensionElement:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.ExtensionElement;
public class UserInfo4XMPP implements ExtensionElement{
    public static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:xmpp:receipts";
    private String elementName = "received ";
    private String id = "";    
    @Override
    public String getElementName() {
        return elementName;
    }
        @Override
    public CharSequence toXML() {  
        return "<received xmlns='" + NAMESPACE + "' id='" + id + "'/>";
    }
    @Override
    public String getNamespace() {
        return NAMESPACE;
    }
    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

The function body is similar to DeliveryReceiptProvider.