# Adding Custom Attributes in Message tag in XMPP packet using asmack for android?

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack, xmppframework

The Message Packet that i want to recieve.

```
  <message to="39@domainname.com/smack" chat_id="73392" 
           custom_packet="true" user_id="44" manager_id="39" time_stamp="0" website_id="0" 
           visitor_name="John" end_time="False" xml:lang="en-us" type="groupchat" 
           from="room73392@conference.domainname.com/39">
           <body>Hello</body> 
           <x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user"> 
           <status xmlns="" code="0"/>   
           </x></message>
```

Message Packet that I am Recieving.

```
<message to="44@domainname.com/Smack" 
    from="room73407@conference.domainname.com/Visitor1171" type="groupchat">
    <body>Hello</body>
    <delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay"></delay>
    <x xmlns="jabber:x:delay" stamp="20120917T05:57:19" 
    from="4732abb5@domainname.com/4732abb5">
    </x></message>
```

I have the Source code of a smack and Here is the packet class. Can anyone help me make my custom packet. Any help Modifying the source code is appreciated.

**Code :**

```
public abstract class Packet {

protected static final String DEFAULT_LANGUAGE =
        java.util.Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().toLowerCase();

private static String DEFAULT_XML_NS = null;

/**
 * Constant used as packetID to indicate that a packet has no id. To indicate that a packet
 * has no id set this constant as the packet's id. When the packet is asked for its id the
 * answer will be <tt>null</tt>.
 */
public static final String ID_NOT_AVAILABLE = "ID_NOT_AVAILABLE";

/**
 * Date format as defined in XEP-0082 - XMPP Date and Time Profiles.
 * The time zone is set to UTC.
 * <p>
 * Date formats are not synchronized. Since multiple threads access the format concurrently,
 * it must be synchronized externally. 
 */
public static final DateFormat XEP_0082_UTC_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
static {
    XEP_0082_UTC_FORMAT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
}


/**
 * A prefix helps to make sure that ID's are unique across mutliple instances.
 */
private static String prefix = StringUtils.randomString(5) + "-";

/**
 * Keeps track of the current increment, which is appended to the prefix to
 * forum a unique ID.
 */
private static long id = 0;

private String xmlns = DEFAULT_XML_NS;

/**
 * Returns the next unique id. Each id made up of a short alphanumeric
 * prefix along with a unique numeric value.
 *
 * @return the next id.
 */
public static synchronized String nextID() {
    return prefix + Long.toString(id++);
}

public static void setDefaultXmlns(String defaultXmlns) {
    DEFAULT_XML_NS = defaultXmlns;
}

private String packetID = null;
private String to = null;
private String from = null;
private final List<PacketExtension> packetExtensions
        = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<PacketExtension>();

private final Map<String,Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
private XMPPError error = null;

/**
 * Returns the unique ID of the packet. The returned value could be <tt>null</tt> when
 * ID_NOT_AVAILABLE was set as the packet's id.
 *
 * @return the packet's unique ID or <tt>null</tt> if the packet's id is not available.
 */
public String getPacketID() {
    if (ID_NOT_AVAILABLE.equals(packetID)) {
        return null;
    }

    if (packetID == null) {
        packetID = nextID();
    }
    return packetID;
}

/**
 * Sets the unique ID of the packet. To indicate that a packet has no id
 * pass the constant ID_NOT_AVAILABLE as the packet's id value.
 *
 * @param packetID the unique ID for the packet.
 */
public void setPacketID(String packetID) {
    this.packetID = packetID;
}

/**
 * Returns who the packet is being sent "to", or <tt>null</tt> if
 * the value is not set. The XMPP protocol often makes the "to"
 * attribute optional, so it does not always need to be set.<p>
 *
 * The StringUtils class provides several useful methods for dealing with
 * XMPP addresses such as parsing the
 * {@link StringUtils#parseBareAddress(String) bare address},
 * {@link StringUtils#parseName(String) user name},
 * {@link StringUtils#parseServer(String) server}, and
 * {@link StringUtils#parseResource(String) resource}.  
 *
 * @return who the packet is being sent to, or <tt>null</tt> if the
 *      value has not been set.
 */
public String getTo() {
    return to;
}

/**
 * Sets who the packet is being sent "to". The XMPP protocol often makes
 * the "to" attribute optional, so it does not always need to be set.
 *
 * @param to who the packet is being sent to.
 */
public void setTo(String to) {
    this.to = to;
}

/**
 * Returns who the packet is being sent "from" or <tt>null</tt> if
 * the value is not set. The XMPP protocol often makes the "from"
 * attribute optional, so it does not always need to be set.<p>
 *
 * The StringUtils class provides several useful methods for dealing with
 * XMPP addresses such as parsing the
 * {@link StringUtils#parseBareAddress(String) bare address},
 * {@link StringUtils#parseName(String) user name},
 * {@link StringUtils#parseServer(String) server}, and
 * {@link StringUtils#parseResource(String) resource}.  
 *
 * @return who the packet is being sent from, or <tt>null</tt> if the
 *      value has not been set.
 */
public String getFrom() {
    return from;
}

/**
 * Sets who the packet is being sent "from". The XMPP protocol often
 * makes the "from" attribute optional, so it does not always need to
 * be set.
 *
 * @param from who the packet is being sent to.
 */
public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
}

/**
 * Returns the error associated with this packet, or <tt>null</tt> if there are
 * no errors.
 *
 * @return the error sub-packet or <tt>null</tt> if there isn't an error.
 */
public XMPPError getError() {
    return error;
}

/**
 * Sets the error for this packet.
 *
 * @param error the error to associate with this packet.
 */
public void setError(XMPPError error) {
    this.error = error;
}

/**
 * Returns an unmodifiable collection of the packet extensions attached to the packet.
 *
 * @return the packet extensions.
 */
public synchronized Collection<PacketExtension> getExtensions() {
    if (packetExtensions == null) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<PacketExtension>(packetExtensions));
}

/**
 * Returns the first extension of this packet that has the given namespace.
 *
 * @param namespace the namespace of the extension that is desired.
 * @return the packet extension with the given namespace.
 */
public PacketExtension getExtension(String namespace) {
    return getExtension(null, namespace);
}

/**
 * Returns the first packet extension that matches the specified element name and
 * namespace, or <tt>null</tt> if it doesn't exist. If the provided elementName is null
 * than only the provided namespace is attempted to be matched. Packet extensions are
 * are arbitrary XML sub-documents in standard XMPP packets. By default, a 
 * DefaultPacketExtension instance will be returned for each extension. However, 
 * PacketExtensionProvider instances can be registered with the 
 * {@link org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.ProviderManager ProviderManager}
 * class to handle custom parsing. In that case, the type of the Object
 * will be determined by the provider.
 *
 * @param elementName the XML element name of the packet extension. (May be null)
 * @param namespace the XML element namespace of the packet extension.
 * @return the extension, or <tt>null</tt> if it doesn't exist.
 */
public PacketExtension getExtension(String elementName, String namespace) {
    if (namespace == null) {
        return null;
    }
    for (PacketExtension ext : packetExtensions) {
        if ((elementName == null || elementName.equals(ext.getElementName()))
                && namespace.equals(ext.getNamespace()))
        {
            return ext;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Adds a packet extension to the packet.
 *
 * @param extension a packet extension.
 */
public void addExtension(PacketExtension extension) {
    packetExtensions.add(extension);
}

/**
 * Removes a packet extension from the packet.
 *
 * @param extension the packet extension to remove.
 */
public void removeExtension(PacketExtension extension)  {
    packetExtensions.remove(extension);
}

/**
 * Returns the packet property with the specified name or <tt>null</tt> if the
 * property doesn't exist. Property values that were orginally primitives will
 * be returned as their object equivalent. For example, an int property will be
 * returned as an Integer, a double as a Double, etc.
 *
 * @param name the name of the property.
 * @return the property, or <tt>null</tt> if the property doesn't exist.
 */
public synchronized Object getProperty(String name) {
    if (properties == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return properties.get(name);
}

/**
 * Sets a property with an Object as the value. The value must be Serializable
 * or an IllegalArgumentException will be thrown.
 *
 * @param name the name of the property.
 * @param value the value of the property.
 */
public synchronized void setProperty(String name, Object value) {
    if (!(value instanceof Serializable)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value must be serialiazble");
    }
    properties.put(name, value);
}

/**
 * Deletes a property.
 *
 * @param name the name of the property to delete.
 */
public synchronized void deleteProperty(String name) {
    if (properties == null) {
        return;
    }
    properties.remove(name);
}

/**
 * Returns an unmodifiable collection of all the property names that are set.
 *
 * @return all property names.
 */
public synchronized Collection<String> getPropertyNames() {
    if (properties == null) {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>(properties.keySet()));
}

/**
 * Returns the packet as XML. Every concrete extension of Packet must implement
 * this method. In addition to writing out packet-specific data, every sub-class
 * should also write out the error and the extensions data if they are defined.
 *
 * @return the XML format of the packet as a String.
 */
public abstract String toXML();

/**
 * Returns the extension sub-packets (including properties data) as an XML
 * String, or the Empty String if there are no packet extensions.
 *
 * @return the extension sub-packets as XML or the Empty String if there
 * are no packet extensions.
 */
protected synchronized String getExtensionsXML() {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    // Add in all standard extension sub-packets.
    for (PacketExtension extension : getExtensions()) {
        buf.append(extension.toXML());
    }
    // Add in packet properties.
    if (properties != null && !properties.isEmpty()) {
        buf.append("<properties xmlns=\"http://www.jivesoftware.com/xmlns/xmpp/properties\">");
        // Loop through all properties and write them out.
        for (String name : getPropertyNames()) {
            Object value = getProperty(name);
            buf.append("<property>");
            buf.append("<name>").append(StringUtils.escapeForXML(name)).append("</name>");
            buf.append("<value type=\"");
            if (value instanceof Integer) {
                buf.append("integer\">").append(value).append("</value>");
            }
            else if (value instanceof Long) {
                buf.append("long\">").append(value).append("</value>");
            }
            else if (value instanceof Float) {
                buf.append("float\">").append(value).append("</value>");
            }
            else if (value instanceof Double) {
                buf.append("double\">").append(value).append("</value>");
            }
            else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
                buf.append("boolean\">").append(value).append("</value>");
            }
            else if (value instanceof String) {
                buf.append("string\">");
                buf.append(StringUtils.escapeForXML((String)value));
                buf.append("</value>");
            }
            // Otherwise, it's a generic Serializable object. Serialized objects are in
            // a binary format, which won't work well inside of XML. Therefore, we base-64
            // encode the binary data before adding it.
            else {
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = null;
                ObjectOutputStream out = null;
                try {
                    byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    out = new ObjectOutputStream(byteStream);
                    out.writeObject(value);
                    buf.append("java-object\">");
                    String encodedVal = StringUtils.encodeBase64(byteStream.toByteArray());
                    buf.append(encodedVal).append("</value>");
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    if (out != null) {
                        try {
                            out.close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            // Ignore.
                        }
                    }
                    if (byteStream != null) {
                        try {
                            byteStream.close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            // Ignore.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            buf.append("</property>");
        }
        buf.append("</properties>");
    }
    return buf.toString();
}

public String getXmlns() {
    return this.xmlns;
}

public static String getDefaultLanguage() {
    return DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Packet packet = (Packet) o;

    if (error != null ? !error.equals(packet.error) : packet.error != null) { return false; }
    if (from != null ? !from.equals(packet.from) : packet.from != null) { return false; }
    if (!packetExtensions.equals(packet.packetExtensions)) { return false; }
    if (packetID != null ? !packetID.equals(packet.packetID) : packet.packetID != null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (properties != null ? !properties.equals(packet.properties)
            : packet.properties != null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (to != null ? !to.equals(packet.to) : packet.to != null)  { return false; }
    return !(xmlns != null ? !xmlns.equals(packet.xmlns) : packet.xmlns != null);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result;
    result = (xmlns != null ? xmlns.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (packetID != null ? packetID.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (to != null ? to.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (from != null ? from.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + packetExtensions.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + properties.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + (error != null ? error.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: **Never** put custom data as extra attributes (`visitor_name`, `end_time`) to already defined XMPP elements (`message`). Always create an extra packet extension to add your custom data, because otherwise you have to fiddly with the source of the XMPP libraries involved.

Comment: See also [XEP-134 2.1](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0134.html#xmpp).

Comment: @Flow yes ur Right about that but at that time, No one gave me such an idea. I would still greatly appreciate if you provide me with some code for creating packet extension and adding custom data to it

Comment: I suggest having a look at the Smack documentation.

Comment: This is not the recommended approach, instead use extension Providers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added new Fields in Packet Class and wrote there Getter and Setter.

```
private String chat_id = null;
private String custom_packet = null;
private String user_id=null;
private String manager_id=null;
private String time_stamp=null;
private String website_id=null;
private String visitor_name=null;
private String end_time=null;




public String getChat_id() {
    return chat_id;
}

public void setChat_id(String chat_id) {
    this.chat_id = chat_id;
}

public String getCustom_packet() {
    return custom_packet;
}

public void setCustom_packet(String custom_packet) {
    this.custom_packet = custom_packet;
}

public String getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public String getManager_id() {
    return manager_id;
}

public void setManager_id(String manager_id) {
    this.manager_id = manager_id;
}

public String getTime_stamp() {
    return time_stamp;
}

public void setTime_stamp(String time_stamp) {
    this.time_stamp = time_stamp;
}

public String getWebsite_id() {
    return website_id;
}

public void setWebsite_id(String website_id) {
    this.website_id = website_id;
}

public String getVisitor_name() {
    return visitor_name;
}

public void setVisitor_name(String visitor_name) {
    this.visitor_name = visitor_name;
}

public String getEnd_time() {
    return end_time;
}

public void setEnd_time(String end_time) {
    this.end_time = end_time;
}
```

Then i added this to PacketParserUtils Class parseMessage() method.

```
    // ------------------------------CUSTOM ATTRIBUTES-----------------------------
    message.setChat_id(parser.getAttributeValue("", "chat_id"));
    message.setCustom_packet(parser.getAttributeValue("", "custom_packet"));
    message.setUser_id(parser.getAttributeValue("", "user_id"));
    message.setManager_id(parser.getAttributeValue("", "manager_id"));
    message.setTime_stamp(parser.getAttributeValue("", "time_stamp"));
    message.setWebsite_id(parser.getAttributeValue("", "website_id"));
    message.setVisitor_name(parser.getAttributeValue("", "visitor_name"));
    message.setEnd_time(parser.getAttributeValue("", "end_time"));

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then i updated the Message Class toXML() method to this.

```
// ------------------------------CUSTOM TAGS-----------------------------

    if(getChat_id()!=null)
    {
        buf.append(" chat_id=\"").append(StringUtils.escapeForXML(getChat_id())).append("\"");

    }
    if(getCustom_packet()!=null)
    {
        buf.append(" custom_packet=\"").append(StringUtils.escapeForXML(getCustom_packet())).append("\"");

    }
    if(getUser_id()!=null)
    {
        buf.append(" user_id=\"").append(StringUtils.escapeForXML(getUser_id())).append("\"");

    }

    if(getManager_id()!=null)
    {
        buf.append(" manager_id=\"").append(StringUtils.escapeForXML(getManager_id())).append("\"");

    }
    if(getTime_stamp()!=null)
    {
        buf.append(" time_stamp=\"").append(StringUtils.escapeForXML(getTime_stamp())).append("\"");

    }
    if(getWebsite_id()!=null)
    {
        buf.append(" website_id=\"").append(StringUtils.escapeForXML(getWebsite_id())).append("\"");

    }
    if(getVisitor_name()!=null)
    {
        buf.append(" visitor_name=\"").append(StringUtils.escapeForXML(getVisitor_name())).append("\"");

    }
    if(getEnd_time()!=null)
    {
        buf.append(" end_time=\"").append(StringUtils.escapeForXML(getEnd_time())).append("\"");

    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This how i was able to Recieve custom attributes in MESSAGE TAG.

Comment: tnx for this answer,but im getting null values of custom attributes.Can u pls help me for this?

Comment: @ChiragShah Did u change the source code properly ?

Comment: yes i got the solution it was a little bit my mistake.

Comment: @ChiragShah Em Glad it helped u :)

Comment: I think this is a good answer but i agree with @Robin that this shouldn't be done

Comment: Don't do this, this is not the recommended approach, instead use extension Providers

Comment: @penguin can you  please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734043/chat-app-for-android-using-a-xmpp-server-and-firebase-cloud-messaging-for-push-n in this it gives user not registered error

Answer (score 8):

Even though I think this is the wrong approach, as I said in your other question.  These are a few guidelines to what you are trying to do.

You don't need to modify Packet, just extend Message to put in your own custom attributes.  This will accomplish what is required for the sending.  For receiving, you will have to modify [PacketParserUtil.parseMessage()](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/util/PacketParserUtils.html#parseMessage%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser%29) to be able to determine whether your custom message or a standard message is being sent and construct and populate as appropriate.  I don't know if the server you are using may have issues with this or not, due to it being non-standard, but it will probably work.

Another simpler option would be to simply add your attributes as properties to the standard Message via [Packet.setProperty()](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/Packet.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) and of course read via the getProperty().  This will create and extension to the packet, but no custom work is required as Smack will already read/write the extension.

Comment: Thankyou very much. This was exactly what i did and it Solved the Problem. I modified the Packet Class and Also Modified the PacketParserUtils class parseMessage() method.

Comment: Can i recieve the above packet without changing the source code ?

Comment: If I do extend PacketParserUtils or the Message class, is there any way to register those classes, or will I have to include all the source code instead of the jar?

Answer (score 1):

If you can add use a custom packet extension like described in smack, then do so. If you're looking to be compatible with a server or non-smack client that does not support such extensions, like if the server won't store it, then use

```
message.addBody("varName","varValue);

<message id='8dbda9a2-1f98-478f-9a65-635f181a6ddc' 
to='oGghwFpcrR@example.com/oGghwFpcrR' type='chat'><body>abcd</body>
<body xml:lang='varName'>varValue</body><thread>8b5342dcc</thread>        
</message>

message.getBody("varName");
```

Not an ideal solution, but who uses multiple langs for an identical message anyway? What Smack *should* allow you to do is register for your own message parsing to replace the default, or at least in addition to the default

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. Here is a generic tag-value solution:

In Packet Class, added:

```
public static ArrayList<String> parseTags = new ArrayList<String>();
public HashMap<String, String> mTags ;
```

Constructor:
mTags = new HashMap ();
Copy constructor:
mTags = p.mTags;

In PacketParserUtils.ParseMessage(), added

```
    if (message.mTags != null) {
        for (int i=0; i<Packet.parseTags.size(); i++) {
            String tag = Packet.parseTags.get(i);
            String value = parser.getAttributeValue("", tag);
            message.mTags.put(tag, value);
        }               
    }
```

In Message.toXML, before the ">" is appended, add:

```
    if (mTags != null) {
        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = mTags.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            String tag = (String) pairs.getKey();
            String value = (String) pairs.getValue(); 
            buf.append(" ").append(tag).append("=\"").append(value).append("\"");
        }               
    }
```

---

Then, in the application, before setting packet handler, add all your custom tags, like:

```
     Packet.parseTags.add(ROOMTYPE);
     Packet.parseTags.add(ROOMNAME);
     Packet.parseTags.add(CHATTYPE);
```

also before sending messages, add things like:

```
     message.mTags.put(ROOMTYPE, "Private");
     message.mTags.put(ROOMNAME, UHInterface.liveSessionID);
     message.mTags.put(MSGTYPE, "Photo");
```

Answer (score -3):

Use `Message.setProperty()` because message class extends  Packet.

In the Message class use in `method String toXML(),  sb.append("<tag_x>").append(String.valueOf(super.getProperty("tag"))).append("</tag_x>");`

And in the project call

```
Message.getProperty
```