# Chat App for Android using a XMPP Server and Firebase Cloud Messaging for Push Notifications

Tags: android, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging, ejabberd, smack

I'm trying to send custom IQ from register device to ejabberd xmpp server for FCM configuration but still i can't received FCM notification and receiving Error like "user not registered at XMPP".

**Step 1 : Created class for Custom IQ**

```
public class IQGetSomething extends IQ {
    public static final String ELEMENT = "push";
    public static final String NAMESPACE = "p1:push";
    String refreshedToken;
    String userName;

    public IQGetSomething(String refreshedToken,String userName) {
        super(ELEMENT, NAMESPACE);
        setType(Type.set);
        this.refreshedToken = refreshedToken;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    protected IQChildElementXmlStringBuilder getIQChildElementBuilder(IQChildElementXmlStringBuilder xml) {
        xml.rightAngleBracket();
        xml.append("<keepalive max=\"120\"/>" +
                "<session duration=\"60\"/>" +
                "<body send=\"all\" groupchat=\"true\" from=" + "\"" + userName + "\"/>" +
                "<status type=\"xa\">Text Message when in push mode</status>" +
                "<offline>true</offline>" +
                "<notification>"+
                "<type>fcm</type>"+
                "<id>" + refreshedToken + "</id>"+
                "</notification>"+
                "<appid>" + "com.appname"+ "</appid>");

        return xml;
    }
}
```

**Step 2 : Send stanza to XMPP**

```
@Override
    public void authenticated(XMPPConnection connection, boolean resumed) {
        SmackService.sConnectionState = ConnectionState.CONNECTED;
        logI("Before n mostly after login  $^&$^$...authenticated ");
        logI("authenticated");

        if (!mConnection.isSmEnabled()) {
            mConnection.setUseStreamManagement(true);
            mConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumption(true);
        }
        if (mConnection.isSmEnabled()) {
            logI("stream M is enabled");
        } else {
            logI("stream M is not enabled");
        }

        final String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        IQGetSomething iqCustomPush = new IQGetSomething(refreshedToken, mUsername);
        iqCustomPush.setStanzaId(refreshedToken);
        Log.d("xml", iqCustomPush.toXML().toString());

        try {
            mConnection.sendStanza(iqCustomPush);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**Step 3 : Set Offline**

```
public void setOffline() {
        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.unavailable);
        try {
            mConnection.sendStanza(presence);
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**LOGCAT

```
01-18 17:48:29.719 10219-10441/com.appname D/xml: 

<iq id='refresh_token' type='set'><push xmlns='p1:push'><keepalive max="120"/><session duration="60"/><body send="all" groupchat="true" from="user_id"/><status type="xa">Text Message when in push mode</status><offline>true</offline><notification><type>fcm</type><id>refresh_token</id></notification><appid>com.appname</appid></push></iq>**
```

Note :- I changed here my refreshtoken with text **"refresh_token"** and package name with **"com.appname"**. If anything i'm doing wrong than help me.