# Add custom attribute to message in asmack

Tags: xmpp, smack, asmack

I am using asmack for xmpp connection.I need to send custom attribute with message.

I have to add "alias" attribute.Like this:

```
<message type="chat" to="admin@localhost/krm11-PC" alias="myalias1" id="aae5a"> 
<body>sd</body> 
</message>
```

How can I achive this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot Read Custom Attributes From Message TAG when using asmack XMPP library for android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454025/cannot-read-custom-attributes-from-message-tag-when-using-asmack-xmpp-library-fo)

Comment: Never invent your own attributes for XMPP top level elements. See also [XEP-134 2.1](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0134.html#xmpp). Instead add an extension `<myextension xmlns='myns'><alias name='myalias1'/>/</myextension>`